# How to Properly Export to CSV Using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, server

May I know how to properly export this script to CSV?

```
Try {

    Invoke-Command -scriptblock {Get-EventLog System -After "7/8/2017" -Before "07/28/2017" | 
    Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq "50" -or $_.EventID -eq "51" -or $_.EventID -eq "55" -or $_.EventID -eq "57" -or $_.EventID -eq "6008"} | 
    FT -Property Machinename, TimeWritten, EntryType, Source, EventID, Message -AutoSize -wrap }  -computername $computer -ErrorAction Stop  
}
Catch {
    Write-Host $Computer "Error/RDC Problem" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Result:
 [image]

Export-CSV command is not working properly when added at the end. It outputs a different set of data.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"? I would expect Format-Csv to output all the properties of the objects, whereas Format-Table will often show a subset that will fit on the screen. Format-Csv is going to a format that won't be constrained by the screen width, so it can (and should) include everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting cmdlets like `Format-Table` don't just change the way the object is displayed, it changes the object itself into something that will display how you want it to. This is part of why it's commonly recommended not to use the formatting cmdlets in scripts or functions.

Instead, you should use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to limit the number of properties passed to `Export-Csv`.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {
    Get-EventLog System -After "7/8/2017" -Before "07/28/2017" | 
    Where-Object { 50, 51, 55, 57, 6008 -contains $_.EventID } | 
    Select-Object -Property MachineName, TimeWritten, EntryType, Source, EventID, Message
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Plus points for making the script shorter too, I didn't know you can work with Where-Object like that :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Try {

    Invoke-Command -scriptblock {Get-EventLog System -After "7/8/2017" -Before "07/28/2017" | 
    Where EventID -in ("50", "51", "55", "57", "6008") | 
    select Machinename, TimeWritten, EntryType, Source, EventID, Message }  -computername $computer -ErrorAction Stop |export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv"  
}
Catch {
    Write-Host $Computer "Error/RDC Problem" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

or may be simply like this :

```
Try 
{
    Get-EventLog System -After "7/8/2017" -Before "07/28/2017" -ComputerName $computer | 
    Where EventID -in ("50", "51", "55", "57", "6008") | 
    select Machinename, TimeWritten, EntryType, Source, EventID, Message |export-csv "c:\temp\result.csv" -NoType
}
Catch 
{
    Write-Host $Computer "Error/RDC Problem" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about bringing the Export-CSV command inside the try block. Thank you for this! +1